# Assigning and Passing Sessions Variables Between Subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, session-variables, subdomain

I am going to create a site that will have have multiple subdomains. For an example:

- `shop.domain.com`
- `blog.domain.com`
- `news.domain.com`
- `account.domain.com`

I would like to know if session variables can be passed between the subdomains. For an example `$_SESSION['variable']` would be accessible on all of the subdomains listed above.

Comment: may be this can halp you [link]http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first have to make sure to store **session data** in a way that all hosts can access them; if they are hosted on the same machine everything is fine, otherwise you might want to use another session handler which e.g. uses a database, memcache, ... to store session data. 
Then you have to make sure the **session id** is available on all subdomains; this can be achieved by setting [ini.session.cookie-domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain).

For more information on sessions you should read the [appropriate chapter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) in the fine php manual.